# JSON /PHP decoding arrays within arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm getting data from this website  "http://watson.kmi.open.ac.uk/API/term/synonyms?term=love"  and turning it into json format using php script.The output in json format looks like this

```
 ( [Term-array-array] => Array ( [Term-array] => Array ( [Term] => Array ( [0] => loves [1] => love ) ) ) )
```

I want to get each individual term e.g loves and love , store them in a array in php so i can use them later on.  Can someone please help me with this ? Thanks

Comment: They already are in an array - why can't you just reference them before you convert it to json?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  (this sorta looks like a homework assignment to me)

Comment: @Emissary Can you please explain further? Sorry this is my first time scripting in php.

Comment: @zipzit its not a homework assignment , i'm trying to build a search engine that uses third party thesaurus to  search a  database. I have tried this  $obj= '{"foo-bar": 12345}';$obj 
print $obj->{'foo-bar'};

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your code - or at least the output of `print_r` on whatever object you are passing to `json_encode`.

Comment: @Emissary 'curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); $a= json_decode($data,true); print_r ($a) ;

Comment: So, you have a PHP array already stored in $a? I don't understand what you are in need of then.

Comment: So... `$terms = $a['Term-array-array']['Term-array']['Term'];` ?

Comment: @DerekS its not stored in a array , sorry i left this out $a = curl_exec($c);

Comment: @Emissary sorry no  $a = curl_exec($c). the variable $a stores the values retrieved from a website.

Comment: Are you having the problem for the nesting of the array, do you already have the array on your hand ?

Comment: So use the variable that the `json_decode` is assigned to - not being funny but this is ***really*** basic stuff, perhaps you'd be better starting from the beggining: http://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha I'm having problem with nesting of the arrays.

Comment: @Emissary I have looked at php manual, I don't understand how to get the value for the nested arrays in the json format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are having problem with the nesting of the arrays (as mentioned in the comment) then you may convert the multi-dimensional array to a flat one dimensional array to ease the process using something like this ([Live Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/FpF0Si)):

```
$a = array(...); // asumed you have the array in $a
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($a));
$array = array();
foreach($it as $v) {
    $array[] = $v;
}
```

Now use it directly from the flat array:

```
echo $array[0]; // loves
echo $array[1]; // love
```

This is an option and you may try this if there are no other side effects in your development process if you convert it to a flat array.

Comment: Welcome and hope it helped you :-)